# How can I add SASS file to bootstrap-vue/webpack (vue-cli project)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

I initialized a project based on [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) and [vue-cli template](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/#vue-cli) ([webpack](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/webpack)) and I do not know how can I add my custom SCSS files to this project.

I create file **src/assets/scss/app.scss** and I added `import './assets/scss/app.scss'` to **src/main.js** file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue"
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import './assets/scss/app.scss' // HERE IS MY CHANGE!!!

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { App }
})
```

but I got ERROR:

```
This relative module was not found:
* ./assets/scss/app.scss in ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
vue init bootstrap-vue/webpack-simple project-name
```

has 'Use sass?' as the fourth option, choosing 'Yes' only configures webpack to extract scss from vue components. To use a stand-alone scss file you'll need to add an extra rule to the webpack.config.js file, e.g.

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        "style-loader",
        "css-loader",
        "sass-loader"
    ]
  }
```

I hope that helps.

When I tried with

```
vue init bootstrap-vue/webpack project-name
```

The utils.js file contains the sass-loader needed for stand-alone scss files like the one you're trying to import, but when I ran

```
npm run build
```

I got a slightly different error to yours:

ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader'

I then tried:

```
npm install sass-loader --save
```

but got:

npm WARN sass-loader@7.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

If you look in the package.json it's using

"webpack": "^2.6.1",

So it looks like bootstrap-vue/webpack has some dependency problems at the moment.

Comment: I want to use `bootstrap-vue/webpack` template. I do not want use `bootstrap-vue/webpack-simple`. In `bootstrap-vue/webpack` I do not have a question about Sass.

Comment: @Cichy I've extended the answer to cover boostrap-vue/webpack looks like that project has sass-loader dependency conflicts